# How to send cookie in localhost to specific domain

Tags: asp.net-core, cookies

I have 2 server:

- WebAPI using AspNetCore listening on production at "https://api.example.com"
- ClientApp using React listening on production at "https://web.example.com"

I setting accept cookie with ".example.com" domain and this working perfect in client app on production. But how can I send cookie when develop ClientApp in local machine?

My fetch:

```js
fetch("https://api.example.com", {credentials: 'include'})
```

WebAPI Setting Cookie:

```cs
.AddCookie(options =>
            {
                
                options.Cookie.Domain = ".example.com";

                if (CurrentEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest;
                    options.Cookie.SameSite = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.SameSiteMode.None;
                }
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.DataProtectionProvider = DataProtectionProvider.Create(new DirectoryInfo(Configuration["DataProtection:KeyFilePath"]));
            })
```

I change hosts file to

```
127.0.0.1 weblocal.example.com
```

Then I access to local web app in browser `weblocal.example.com` and trying fetching data from `weblocal.example.com` to `api.example.com` but Cookie wasn't send in Request Header.

How can I test cookie without deploy a `webapi app` in local-machine?

Comment: Hello, Is there anything else that I can help you on this?

Answer (score 0):

> I setting accept cookie with ".example.com" domain and this working
> perfect in client app on production. But how can I send cookie when
> develop ClientApp in local machine?

In order to provide some protection against cross-site request forgery (CSRF) attacks and due to numerous security reason, asp.net core regardless of it's version, currently allow to set cookie in parent domain and its subdomain.

If you have gone through the [CookieOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.cookieoptions?view=aspnetcore-7.0) class, you would seen [domain property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.cookieoptions.domain?view=aspnetcore-7.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-http-cookieoptions-domain) so while you are telling localhost that's means your application running either in visual studio or IIS which running in local machine, then how do you set domain property?

As per the cookie configuration, we cannot set the domain property to something different than your parent or sub-domain.

However, if you deploy your application on a different server and access it from *example.com then the domain property of the cookie will be correctly set.
This is how cookie in asp.net core or .NET-6/7 intented to design.

[image]

> How can I test cookie without deploy a webapi app in local-machine?

Now, pointing to your question, we cannot do that or configure cookie this way. Anything other than main domain or sub-domain we cannot set cookie. This is involved lot of security concerns, and not supported by design.

**Note:** Please [refer to this document for more details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cookie-sharing?view=aspnetcore-7.0) here.

Comment: Sorry for late. This not about set-cookie. Cookie still set on "weblocal.example.com". They only wasn't sent follow request from client

Comment: Thanks for your response, I got your point.